# AngularJs/Bootstrap modal won't show up though it seems to work

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I used a bootstrap template and integrated it with AngularJs. When I click the button which calls the modal, I can tell that the call works because the "fade" animation comes out. However, the content of the modal won't show up. I included "`ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js`" in my project.

author.html:

```
    <html lang="en" data-ng-app="lmsApp">
        <script src="../js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
        ...
        <body data-ng-controller="authorCtrl">
            ...
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="showAddAuthorModal()">Add Author</button>
            </div> 
            ...
        </body>
    </html>
```

app.js:

```
var lmsModule = angular.module('lmsApp', [ 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap' ]);

lmsModule.controller('authorCtrl', function($scope, $http, $modal) {
    $scope.showAddAuthorModal = function() {
        addAuthorModal = $modal.open({
            templateUrl : "../templates/addAuthor.html",
            controller : "addAuthorCtrl"
        });
    };
});
```

addAuthor.html (the html file for the modal):

```
<section data-ng-controller="addAuthorCtrl">
    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"
                        data-ng-click="cancel();">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Author</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input class=" form-control" type="text"
                        placeholder="Please Type Author Name"
                        data-ng-model="addAuthorName" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary"
                        data-ng-click="save();">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-danger"
                        data-ng-click="cancel();">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Anyone knows why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?  Are you getting a 404 on `addAuthor.html`?

Comment: is your addAuthor.html code complete? or you missed out something?

Comment: @Tom, Hi Tom, there are no errors in the console. and /addAuthor.html page works.

Comment: @V31 Hi V31, I am migrating from my previous project which did not use AngularJs and I copied most of code, so I am sure that the html code is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the modal inside a script tag.
Removed the fade and modal class as well.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="addAuthor.html">
   <section data-ng-controller="addAuthorCtrl">
    <div class="">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"
                        data-ng-click="cancel();">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Author</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input class=" form-control" type="text"
                        placeholder="Please Type Author Name"
                        data-ng-model="addAuthorName" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary"
                        data-ng-click="save();">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-danger"
                        data-ng-click="cancel();">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, I tried this, still got the same result: the modal did not work :(

Comment: can you come up with a quick jsfiddle/plunkr so that we can have a look at the problem

Comment: I am not sure if I successfully put my code onto jsfiddle, here is the link anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/ealonwang/owzg4h60/2/

Comment: remove the fade class and then try.

Comment: yeah the fiddle will not work all the js should be external dependencies.

Comment: Oh wow!!! The modal really comes out, although it is not exactly the perfect one I want. Thanks so much!

Comment: can you explain a little bit why it kind of works when I remove class "modal fade"?

Comment: Actually, now two overlapping modals come out but it is better than nothing. :)

Comment: The ui bootstrap will apply the modal fade class by its own, need not add it by our self. Please accept the answer if it solves your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will fix the remaining problems!